# Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined at Object.runr

Tags: android, cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a problem with my develop because when I try `ionic serve` or every command of ionic or cordova, make me an error. A img to display:

[image]

I tried everything and search it but nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to downgrade your Ionic CLI version. Try the following:

npm uninstall -g ionic

npm install -g ionic@2.1.0

This might be an issue just with Ionic 1 apps, and not with Ionic 2.